# Vue "These relative modules were not found" when using scss file

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap theme in my Vue application. Unfortunately the Bootstrap theme has no reference implementation for Vue. So I need to configure everything on my own.

What I want to do is, I want use the scss-files provided by the theme in Vue. So my App.vue component is pretty simple:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "@/assets/base.scss";
</style>
```

The "base.scss" file contains imports all dependencies. So, when I run my Vue application using "npm run serve", I get the following error:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 10 errors
>
> This dependency was not found:
>
> - -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!typicons.font/src/font/typicons.css
>   in ./node_modules/cs
>   s-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist /cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save
> -!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!typicons.fo
> nt/src/font/typicons.css
>
> These relative modules were not found:
>
> - ./components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.eot in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/
>   sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.eot?w118d in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_mo
>   dules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.svg?w118d in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_mo
>   dules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.ttf?w118d in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_mo
>   dules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.woff2?w118d in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_
>   modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.woff?w118d in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_m
>   odules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./components/slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sa
>   ss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./utils/images/logo-inverse.png in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs
>   .js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
> - ./utils/images/logo.png in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref
>   --8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=scss&
>   Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked,
>   lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

The referenced files are exist in the "@/assets/components/..." directory. But my problem is that I've no idea how I can set a relative path (e.g. "@/assets") searchs for the components. Furthermore there's no variable in the "base.scss" file I can adjust to set the relativ path. I also don't want modify the "base.scss" file because it comes from the theme.
I've no idea how to fix it this. I already tried to set the corresponding webpack-chain in vue.config.js without any success:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('fonts')
      .test(/\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/)
      .use('file-loader')
      .loader('file-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options = {
          name: '@/assets/[path][name].[ext]'
        }
        return options
      })
      .end()
}
```

I hope anyone can help solving this problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue by simply importing the "base.scss" in the "main.js" file and use it:

```
import theme from '@/assets/base.scss'
Vue.use(theme)
```